# How "where" operates in Linq-to-Entities

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `Products` and `Images` table in SQL Server, along with a many-to-many `ProductImages` link table and have an Entity Framework (VS2012, .NET4.5) model generated against this structure.

I have a WCF service with a method, `GetImageList`, which lists the images associated with a product. For speed, I only want to return a couple of columns from the `Images` table, notably excluding the `ImageBinary` and `ImageThumbnailBinary` columns which can be quite large as we store high-resolution images in there.

To prove the point of my query, I decided to only try and get images with a filename of `fred.jpg`.

To begin with, I started off by getting the `Product` and using the navigation properties:

```
Product p = ctx.Products.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Code == productCode);

if (p != null)
{
    var images = p.Images.Where(x => (x.FileName == "fred.jpg") && (!imageTypeId.HasValue || x.ImageTypeId == imageTypeId))
        .Select(x =>
            new
            {
                x.ID,
                x.FileName,
                x.MaxAvailableHeight,
                x.MaxAvailableWidth,
                ImageTypeName = x.ImageType.Name,
                x.FileDescription,
                HasCMYK = (x.CMYKImage != null)
            }
        ).ToList();
}
```

I was surprised to discover that this query was still slow, despite adding a where clause and only selecting the columns I wanted. When I ran SQL Profiler, I discovered that this query translated to getting *every* column for *every* image for the product, and then performed the filter and select in-memory. Here was the associated SQL Server trace, which took 3541ms to execute (notice the lack of filtering for fred.jpg and bringing back every column):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent2].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent2].[MimeType] AS [MimeType], 
[Extent2].[ImageTypeId] AS [ImageTypeId], 
[Extent2].[ImageBinary] AS [ImageBinary], 
[Extent2].[ImageThumbnailBinary] AS [ImageThumbnailBinary], 
[Extent2].[FileSizeKb] AS [FileSizeKb], 
[Extent2].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
[Extent2].[FileDescription] AS [FileDescription], 
[Extent2].[MaxAvailableHeight] AS [MaxAvailableHeight], 
[Extent2].[MaxAvailableWidth] AS [MaxAvailableWidth], 
[Extent2].[CMYKImage] AS [CMYKImage], 
[Extent2].[SageStockItemID] AS [SageStockItemID]
FROM  [product].[ProductImages] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [product].[Images] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ImageID] = [Extent2].[ID]
WHERE [Extent1].[ProductID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=125
```

I then decided that instead of starting at the `Product` and using `.Images.Where`, I would start directly at the context, and add a where clause for the product ID I was interested in, as follows:

```
var images = ctx.Images.Where(x => (x.Products.Any(y => y.ID == 125)) && (x.FileName == "fred.jpg") && (!imageTypeId.HasValue || x.ImageTypeId == imageTypeId))
    .Select(x =>
        new
        {
            x.ID,
            x.FileName,
            x.MaxAvailableHeight,
            x.MaxAvailableWidth,
            ImageTypeName = x.ImageType.Name,
            x.FileDescription,
            HasCMYK = (x.CMYKImage != null)
        }
    ).ToList();
```

To my surprise, this worked exactly as I would want. The SQL translated as below, which includes only the columns I want and the filters I want:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
[Extent1].[MaxAvailableHeight] AS [MaxAvailableHeight], 
[Extent1].[MaxAvailableWidth] AS [MaxAvailableWidth], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[FileDescription] AS [FileDescription], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[CMYKImage] IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ([Extent1].[CMYKImage] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  [product].[Images] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ImageTypes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ImageTypeId] = [Extent2].[ID]
WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [product].[ProductImages] AS [Extent3]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ID] = [Extent3].[ImageID]) AND (125 = [Extent3].[ProductID])
)) AND (''fred.jpg'' = [Extent1].[FileName]) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL OR [Extent1].[ImageTypeId] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0=1,@p__linq__1=1
```

This query took 0ms to execute according to SQL Server profiler - instant!

So, what's going on here, why - when I start at the product and go to `.Images` does it load everything, but if I start at the entity data context and go to `.Images` with the additional filter for the product ID, it works perfectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in the first example you first load a `Product`. Then, as far as Entity Framework is concerned, you do

```
p.Images
```

everything that happens around that call is of no interest to EF. That is because EF always loads complete entity collections *and* materializes entities in a complete state. It won't load the `Images` collection filtered by the `Where` phrase. And it won't load `Image`s that only have the properties in the `Select` phrase.

In the second example *not a single entity* is loaded by EF, because you only fetch a projection and no complete entities (no `Product` and no `Image`). If you're in the DbContext API, you can verify that by checking `context.Products.Local.Count`.

There is a way to do a projection from an entity's collection. Following your example that would be something like:

```
context.Entry(p).Collection(x => x.Images).Query()
       .Select(x => new
                    {
                        x.ID,
                        x.FileName,
                        ....
```